# How to add new variables to arrays in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an array initialized like this:

```
chapters:
  - number: 13
    latin: >-
      Some Latin text...
    german: >-
      Some German text...
  - latin: >-
      Some Latin text...
    german: >-
      Some German text...
  - latin: >-
      Some Latin text...
    german: >-
      Some German text...
```

and so on.

Now I want to automatically determine which numbers the chapters should have which I haven't assigned one to yet. Because I need them later, I want to write them into the number variable, so each chapter has a set number.

```
{% assign chapterNumber = 0 %}
{% for chapter in page.chapters %}
    {% if chapter.number == nil %}
        {% assign chapter.number = chapterNumber | plus: 1 %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapter.number %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapter.number %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, the chapter.number will remain empty, why? Can't it be filled because it's nil? Is it not possible to add the variable into the array in Liquid?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an array, this is a hash.

Meanwhile, you can create and [manipulate an array](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters), you cannot natively create or alter a hash with liquid.

The only way to accomplish this is by using a [filter plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/filters/).

Comment: Ah, ok! I'm relatively net to jekyll development, so there are still a few things I don't understand that well.  Yeah, I'll try to develop my own filter, looks like the only good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand David correctly, this should work:

```
{% assign chapterNumber = 0 %}
{% for chapter in page.chapters %}
    {% if chapter.number == nil %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapterNumber | plus: 1 %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapter.number %}
    {% endif %}

    ... code that handles the chapter and references chapterNumber

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have done it before, but due to the segmentation to different files I have, I had to copy this block of code to every location I wanted to have the chapter number.  That's why I wanted to do it one time only and then having it available everywhere, but I guess it can't be helped then...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [this plugin](https://github.com/ferrriii/JekylPlugins#filter-to-add-property-to-hash-addproprb) and below code:

```
{% assign chapterNumber = 0 %}
{% for chapter in page.chapters %}
    {% if chapter.number == nil %}
        {% assign chapter = chapter | addProp: "number", 1 %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapter.number %}
    {% else %}
        {% assign chapterNumber = chapter.number %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```