# Liquid - two variables named the same thing, but i need the highest value returned

Tags: liquid

I have two variables name "price" and both have different values, one is 100, one is 150.

I want to return only the 150 value. What are my options?

```
{% assign myvariable = 69.99 %}
{% assign myvariable = 39.99 %}
{{ myvariable }} <- This should return 69.99
```

Clean up will be an option later, but not at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. first Create an array of your two variables.
   `{% assign myArray = [variable1, variable1] %}`
   [Create an array in Shopify's liquid](https://heliumdev.com/blog/create-an-array-in-shopifys-liquid)
2. use sort https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort/
3. use first (it Returns the first item of an array)  https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/

Comment: Hi, the items are not part of an array

Comment: maybe this helps to create a array of your variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141537/how-to-add-new-variables-to-arrays-in-liquid